# Showing Matplotlib graphs in a canvas tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i want to display a graph in a canvas. The GUI was written in tkinter using python 2.7.

```
    self.plotting(x, pa, y)
    savefig("Omegakillerisawesome.png")
    im=PhotoImage(file="Omegakillerisawesome.png")
    self.canvasForGraph.create_image(500, 350, anchor=CENTER, image=im)
    #show()
    os.remove('Omegakillerisawesome.png')
```

The plotting function was implemented by me. accepting x,y values. so i'm hoping to show the graph in a canvas. so i'm saving the graph in the directory and reloading the image to the canvas. The problem is the .png file is not appearing in the canvas.

but if i uncomment the show() function the image comes up in the canvas as well as the usual window that graphs are displayed. i don't want that. i only want the graph to show up in the canvas.

please help. i'm a newbie.

[edit]

```
    depth=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    temp=[9,8,7,6,5,4]
    plot(depth,temp)
    show()
```

this shows me a frame with my graph in it. but i want to do is display the graph inside a canvas widget using tkinter. but i dont want the usual frame that comes with the latter code. i just want the graph plotted inside the canvas no more.

that is what i'm trying to achieve from the first piece of code.

thanks.

Comment: Providing a [mcve] of the issue increases the chances of obtaining a satisfying answer drastically. Also consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: I am assuming that the code fragment you posted is from a function, such that ``im`` is a local variable.  This is a common Tkinter problem - when the variable goes out of scope, the image gets garbage collected, even though the canvas (or other widget) is still using it.  The solution is to put this variable somewhere that will live as long as the canvas does - ``self.im``, perhaps.